# Can i suppress LLDB's extraneous output

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb

I'm running LLDB in XCode 4.6.3 and I'd like to be able to just see my own output that I tell LLDB to print, without it doing it's own annotations.  For example, for each line of my own output, I get these two lines (shown at end below) of additional output that are irrelevant to my needs.

So for every 10 lines of my own output, I get a total of 30 lines in the debug window.  Really distracting and pointless.

I've search the lldb.llvm.org website, but don't see anything that would do what i'm asking.

```
Process 13573 resuming
Command #2 'continue' continued the target.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pose a very general question, but your example is just about the "restarting" notification that you get from breakpoint commands that contain "continue" commands somewhere in them.

For that specific issue, though there is no such thing yet, it would be straightforward to add a --quiet flag to the "breakpoint command add" command.  File a bug either with the lldb bugzilla or bugreporter.apple.com or if you are feeling adventurous check out the lldb sources and have at it yourself. A patch to that effect would be gladly accepted.

If there are other places where you feel the command output is too chatty, ask about them individually.

Answer (score -1):

If you write a breakpoint script `myscript.py` like

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import lldb

def dostuff(frame, bp_local, internal_dict):
    # Do stuff with frame ...
    print("Hello world")
    return False
```

and add it on a breakpoint (say ID 1) with:

```
(lldb) command script import myscript.py
(lldb) breakpoint command add -F myscript.dostuff 1
```

the breakpoint will not stop; it will continue silently, printing as many `"Hello world"` strings as the times breakpoint 1 hits. The reason is because the value `False` is returned from the script function. Any other value makes it stop and output backtrace information.

See the reference at https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#running-a-python-script-when-a-breakpoint-gets-hit